# Symfony 3 Routing for custom reusable Bundle ignored

Tags: php, symfony, bundle

I'm creating a reusable bundle for my projects which depends heavily on overrides. Weirdly at some point my routing got ignored and I can't get it to work.

[Note: AppBundle extends MyBundle](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/inheritance.html)

routing.yml

```
my:
    resource: '@MyBundle/Controller/'
    type: annotation
app:
    resource: '@AppBundle/Controller/'
    type: annotation
```

src/MyBundle/Controller/IndexController.php

```
<?php

namespace MyBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;

class IndexController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Index
     *
     * @Route("/", name="index")
     * @Method("GET")
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        return $this->render('index.html.twig');
    }

}
```

composer.json

```
...
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "AppBundle\\": "src/AppBundle",
        "MyBundle\\": "src/MyBundle"
    },
    "classmap": [
        "app/AppKernel.php",
        "app/AppCache.php"
    ]
},
...
```

But I still get a **NotFoundHttpException - No route found for "GET /"**

Am I missing some special configuration for bundles?

Update: obviously it has something to do with parenting the bundle. When I remove the getParent() function everything works as expected again - however I need this to override the bundle.

```
namespace AppBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class AppBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'MyBundle';
    }

}
```

Comment: What Symfony version are you using?

Comment: 3.3.10 to be exact

Comment: Have you tried clearing the cache?

Comment: Multiple times of course ;-)

Comment: See update: using symfony inheritance causes this problem - however this is a needed function. So, where is the conflict here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try '../../src/MyBundle/Controller' and '../../src/AppBundle/Controller'

It's [known issue](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/10335), but "[bundle inheritance is now deprecated and will be removed in Symfony 4](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/10335#issuecomment-334833419)".

Comment: Thanks, this works, but I would be glad to receive some more information about this. It is kind of unexpected.

Comment: Thank you. Well that's a shame. But you may help with another solution: I'm having a MyBundle/Model/ImportNewsletterModel.php with a function like getRecipiants() which returns an array of emails. This function is different from app to app. I initially thought of overriding the file when needed, but it seems to be a bad practice - so how should I implement this?

Comment: I think, ImportNewsletterModel can be an abstract class (BaseImportNewsletterModel) and in different apps u can extend it and implement getRecipiants() method and other methods what different from app to app

Comment: Thanks but say AppBundle/ImpNlModel.php extends MyBundle/ImpNlModel.php, how do I get the results back to the MyBundle Controller (MyBundle/Controller/Newsletter.php - this for handles the results of getReceipients())?

Comment: What's wrong with `$emails = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:ImpNlModel')->getReceipients();` in MyBundle/Controller/Newsletter.php ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158442/discussion-between-snegirekk-and-ptmr-io).